# Em R, usando o pacote plotly, posso plotar o mapa do Brasil e seus estados?

Tags: r

Eu gosto muito do pacote plotly para fazer gráficos interativos. Mas na hora de fazer mapas, não encontrei até agora uma maneira de fazer o mapa do Brasil e seus estados...
Por exemplo, retirei este código do próprio site

```
library(plotly)
df <-read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_us_cities.csv')
df$hover <- paste(df$name, "Population", df$pop/1e6, " million")

df$q <- with(df, cut(pop, quantile(pop), include.lowest = T))
levels(df$q) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"), "Quantile")
df$q <- as.ordered(df$q)

g <- list(
scope = 'usa',
projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
showland = TRUE,
landcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
subunitwidth = 1,
countrywidth = 1,
subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
countrycolor = toRGB("white")
)

plot_ly(df, lon = lon, lat = lat, text = hover,
    marker = list(size = sqrt(pop/10000) + 1, line = list(width = 0)),
    color = q, type = 'scattergeo', locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
layout(title = '2014 US city populations<br>(Click legend to toggle)', geo = g)
```

Fiz um print do resultado...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, gostaria de saber se é possível costumizar o meu mapa usando um shapefile podendo ser do Brasil ou algum estado brasileiro com algumas divisões regionais, tudo fornecido pelo próprio shapefile

é possível?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usando dados do pacote `maps` tem-se as cidades:

```
library(maps)
dfb<-world.cities[world.cities$country.etc=="Brazil",]
library(plotly)
dfb$hover <- paste(dfb$name, "Pop", dfb$pop/1e6, " milloes")

dfb$q <- with(dfb, cut(pop, quantile(pop), include.lowest = T))
levels(dfb$q) <- paste(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"), "Quantile")
dfb$q <- as.ordered(dfb$q)

g <- list(
  scope = 'south america',
  #projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  subunitwidth = 1,
  countrywidth = 1,
  subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("white")
)

plot_ly(dfb, lon = long, lat = lat, text = hover,
        marker = list(size = sqrt(pop/10000) + 1, line = list(width = 0)),
        color = q, type = 'scattergeo', locationmode = 'country names') %>%
  layout(title = 'Populations<br>(Click legend to toggle)', geo = g)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ter o mapa com os estados seria necessário um banco de dados com as coordenadas e informações dos estados para substituir o `dfb`.

Comment: Isto é sensacional...  eu tenho o shapefile dos estados do Brasil, pena que não dá para desenhar da mesma forma que é feita a divisão entre os países.